# asp.net mvc2 sitemap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

what is the best way to create google compliant sitemap in asp.net mvc2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to **Tomas Lycken**'s answer, the [MVC Sitemap Provider](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) is very easy to use and didn't gave me any headaches.

I've used it with annotations directly on the controller methods and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "asp.net mvc sitemap", I found the [ASP.NET MVC Sitemap Provider](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) which looks promising. I've never tried it, though...